# gnuplot angstrom label with Times-Roman font

Tags: fonts, label, gnuplot

I'm trying to produce a plot where I have the character Å (angstroms) in the x axis. Moreover, I want this character to be in the same font as the rest of the graph, that is I want to use Times-Roman. If I use the following code:

```
set encoding iso_8859_1
set term postscript eps enhanced color "Times-Roman, 32"
set output "angstroms.eps"
set xlabel "Try1  {A}  ({\305})"
plot sin(x)
```

I obtain this figure:
[image]

(note: the figure I get is in eps format, but I have to upload a jpg to stackoverflow)

If I remove the {A}, or change it into anything else like {B} I get this:
[image]

Finally, if I write:

```
set xlabel "Try1   (/E {\305})"
```

I get
[image]
where the Å symbol changed to sans serif font.

What's going on? Thanks for any help, Cheers!

/Luca

Comment: I can't reproduce this with `gnuplot` versions 4.6.0, 4.6.3 and 4.7 (2013-09-23) on Debian x86_64. Can you also make a single script and plot for checking. I used `set label at graph 0.1, graph 0.75 "Try1  {A}  ({\305})"; set label at graph 0.1, graph 0.5 "Try1  {B}  ({\305})"; set label at graph 0.1, graph 0.25 "Try1   ({\305})"`.

Comment: @Christoph I am using gnuplot version 4.2 on an somewhat old mac (Mac OS X 10.7.5). If I use your script, that is only graph labels, I can see angstrom signs on any label. BUT if I use the last one also as xlabel, all of them disappear. I'll try on a linux box.

Comment: @Christoph I tried on a linux box with gnuplot 4.6. I still get the same result if, in addition to your label lines, I add `set xlabel  "Try1    ({\305})"`. No label shows anymore any Å sign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here two different scripts, which work for me with Debian x86_64:

```
set encoding utf8 
set term postscript eps enhanced color "Times-Roman, 32"
set output "angstroms-utf8.eps"
set label at graph 0.1, graph 0.75 "Try1 {A} (Å)"
set label at graph 0.1, graph 0.5 "Try1 {B} (Å)"
set label at graph 0.1, graph 0.25 "Try1 (Å)"
set xlabel "Try1 (Å)"
plot sin(x)
```

I tested this one with 4.6.3 (needs at least 4.4 because of the `utf8` encoding). As angstrom signs I used the [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE (U+00C5)](http://www.decodeunicode.org/en/u+00c5).

The other script is

```
set encoding iso_8859_1
set term postscript eps enhanced color "Times-Roman, 32"
set output "angstroms.eps"
set label at graph 0.1, graph 0.75 "Try1 {A} ({\305})"
set label at graph 0.1, graph 0.5 "Try1 {B} ({\305})"
set label at graph 0.1, graph 0.25 "Try1 ({\305})"
set xlabel "Try1 ({\305})"
plot sin(x)
```

That one I tested with 4.2.0 and 4.6.3. All variants give the same result:

[image]

I obtained that `png` using:

```
epstopdf angstroms-utf8.eps && pdftocairo -r 150 -png angstroms-utf8.pdf
```

Comment: I wanted to have directly eps, but I did not try the simplest form, that is directly typing the Å symbol. It works for me too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time I found also this workaround, even if it is not so elegant:

```
set xlabel 'Distance ~A{1{^\260}}'
```