# About gnuplot special / greek characters

Tags: gnuplot

Following is my code

```
reset
set encoding iso_8859_1
set terminal png enhanced
set output 'HF_300K_rdf_2.png'
set xlabel 'r({/305})'
plot x
```

But when I execute this script,

```
gdImageStringFT: Could not find/open font while printing string ) with font 305
```

This error shows, and that angstrom character never appears in the picture.

How can I escape from this situation?

Also, png format cannot designate font and color while using terminal command. Are there any way to use font and color png format?

Thanks

Comment: The question [gnuplot angstrom label with Times-Roman font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141767/gnuplot-angstrom-label-with-times-roman-font) seems to be a duplicate. I also reduced your example to the minimum. You don't need a data file to show the problem with the labels.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Use the `pngcairo` terminal.  This produces higher-quality images in general than the `png` terminal.
2. See if you can avoid magic number codes for symbols.  These days you can often use Unicode characters directly in label strings; try `set xlabel 'r(Å)'` and see if it works.

As @Christoph mentioned this may be a duplicate of [gnuplot angstrom label with Times-Roman font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141767/gnuplot-angstrom-label-with-times-roman-font).