# Add angstrom unit in the label for gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I know some other people have asked the similar questions, but when I try the code they used, it does not give the angstrom unit. 
All I want to do is to add an angstrom unit for my ylabel. Here is the code I used:

```
set termoption enhanced
set encoding iso_8859_1
set ylabel 'B - O ({\305})'
```

But instead of showing angstrom it shows:

[image]
It seems that I am still at the text base, how can I access to E?

Comment: Which OS and terminal are you using? Not all terminals support special characters.

Comment: I am using the gnuplot on Mac. What command should I use then? Is that because of the "set encoding"?

Comment: Which terminal do you use? pngcairo, postscript?

Comment: @Christoph: I actually never thought about the type of terminal that I used. I just opened the terminal and that's it. Could you please tell me the codes for both cases? I have been looking for it a few days.

Comment: For me, the following works fine: `set termoption enhanced; set encoding iso_8859_1; set xlabel '\305'; plot x`. See also the question [gnuplot angstrom label with Times-Roman font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141767/gnuplot-angstrom-label-with-times-roman-font) and my answer there.

Comment: @Christoph: I followed your answer but my figure still cannot show angstrom.

Comment: Again: which terminal do you use? Which gnuplot version? Have you tried using the correct character instead of the octal code?